# cant logout of website with c# webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying to use c# webbrowser control to view mobile version of twitter. I have a button in my windows form which is meant to log me out of the site but i cannot get it to work.

here is the immediate html code:

> span class="w-button-common w-button"> input name="commit"
>   type="submit" value="Sign out" /

i have tried:

**webBrowser1.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");**

but there are a few buttons with type="submit" on the page.

How do i get it to click the right one?

if you would like me to provide the full source of the page then please ask :)

Answer (score 0):

In the past I used the WebBrowser control to interact directly with the DOM using javascript calls like this:

```
browser.Navigate(string.Format(@"javascript:void({0})", jsAction));
```

Of course I know you already did something like this with InvokeMemeber() but since I have no further experience with the WebBrowser interface I can just talk about what I've said before. Using javascript I could achieve any result a real user could. With the method I described you may try, in a javascript context, to enumerate the controls you are trying to address and then call the `.click` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I know no JavaScript at all so can't do it using js

Answer (score 0):

Mhh try it with the normal click Methode.

Get a HtmlElementCollection with

`HtmlElementCollection collection = webBrowser1.Document.getElementsByTagName("select");`

Look through it in Debug Mode, until you know which one is your button.

Than perform the click with:

```
collection[x(whereever your button is)].InvokeMember("click");
```